# How to serialize a list with different element names into one list with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to serialize the following xml response into one `List<String>` object:

```
<result>
    <a1/>
    <a2/>
    ...
    <a20/>
</result>
```

Like:

```
public class Result { 
     //should contain a1... a20
     private List<String> list;
}
```

Is that possible at all?

Background: a webservice that I have no control of is offering several of those "lists" in the XML response. But inside those lists the listelements are named with an index, like `a20`. I don't want jaxb to generate like 20 bean properties for this.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible directly as `java.lang.String`. However some conversion like below could do the trick.

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "any"
    })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "result")
    public class Result {

        @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
        public List<Object> any;

        public List<Object> getAny() {
            if (any == null) {
                any = new ArrayList<Object>();
            }
            return this.any;
        }
}
```

**parsing code :**

```
Result rs = (Result) JAXBUtils.generateObjects(...) // unmarshalling code.

for(Object s : result.getAny()) {
          System.out.println("response: " + ((ElementNSImpl)s).getTextContent());
   }
```

**example :**

**sample.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<result>
    <a1>one</a1>
    <a2>two</a2>
    <a20>three</a20>
</result>
```

**output:**

```
response: one
response: two
response: three
```

Comment: What instanceof will `Object`s of the list be?

You are casting it to `ElementNSImpl` for sysout. Are they always of that type? If so, could I also write `List<ElementNSImpl> any;` in my bean?

Comment: yes it is `ElementNSImpl` because the type is unknown. You can get DOM of the element using `getOwnerDocument` and work on it as well. `org.w3c.dom.Document document = elementNsimpl.getOwnerDocument()`